How to identify that an image in canvas html element is loaded or not
I need to capture the time taken for displaying an image in Canvas HTML element using selenium after clicking a button/key press. Can you help with an example, Thanks

Your question cannot be comprehensively answered because essential data is missing, here is a generic piece of code which you can either use as is or adapt to your needs:
import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait

import java.time.Duration

WDS.browser.get("http://example.com")

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, Duration.ofSeconds(30))
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("yourCanvasElementId")))

long before = System.currentTimeMillis()
wait.until {
    WDS.browser.executeScript("""
            var canvas = document.getElementById('yourCanvasElementId');
            return canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data.length > 0;
        """)
}

long after = System.currentTimeMillis()
long delta = after - before

WDS.log.info("Time taken for image to load in canvas: ${delta} ms")

More information:

How to automate charts (Canvas Element) using Javascript in selenium
How to Use JMeter for Selenium WebDriver Testing


try with this
Set Up the Browser:
driver = webdriver.Chrome() starts a new instance of the Chrome browser using Selenium. Think of this as opening up a fresh browser window that we can control with code.
Navigate to a Webpage:
driver.get("https://your-url-here.com") directs the browser to a specific webpage URL. It’s like typing the website address in the address bar and pressing Enter.
Pause to Ensure the Page Loads:
time.sleep(2) pauses the script for 2 seconds to let the webpage load fully. Without this pause, the script might try to interact with elements before they are available.
Find and Click a Button on the Page:
button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "button-id") locates a button on the webpage using its unique ID (replace "button-id" with the actual ID). It’s like saying, “Find the button that has this specific ID.”


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Open the target webpage
driver.get("mohammed.com") //write your url here


time.sleep(2)


button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "button-id") // your button id



script = """
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas-id');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var start = performance.now();

function measureTime() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        var end = performance.now();
        var timeTaken = end - start;
        return timeTaken;
    };
    img.src = 'URL_OF_YOUR_IMAGE';
}

measureTime();
"""

button.click()

time_taken = driver.execute_script(script)

print(f"Time taken to display the image: {time_taken} ms")

driver.quit()




img.src = 'URL_OF_YOUR_IMAGE'--> i have no clue about this ,as it is coming from other site and displayed in Canvas element in my application. In that case how to measure time taken for load.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
